# Is the basin of attraction to infinity open, and is it contained in the Fatou set?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-dynamics

I have managed to show that the interior of the basin of attraction to infinity, $A(\infty)$, is contained in the Fatou set so in order to show that $A(\infty)$ is in the Fatou set, I need to show that $A(\infty)$ is open.

My best guess is to assume, for a contradiction, that $z$ is in $A(\infty)$ but not the Fatou set, so there must be a sequence of points converging to $z$ whose iterates do not tend to infinity, but I'm a bit lost with this.

Is there a fairly simple proof? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is $\infty$ assumed to be an *attracting* fixed point?

Comment: This is not for any particular function, I am trying to see if this works for all non-linear entire functions. The definition given in lectures for $A(\infty)$ is the set of points z with $f^n(z)$ tending to $\infty$ (pointwise). I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: If $\infty$ is a *repelling* fixed point then it is in the Julia set, and  $A(\infty)$ is not open. I think it is even more complicated for indifferent fixed points.

Comment: Only maps $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ are used for this iteration theory section in my lectures, so I don't think $\infty$ is considered as a fixpoint at all. Definition for periodic points only applies to $z\in \mathbb{C}$ for some reason.

Comment: Is what you are saying that if $f(\infty)=\infty$ and $|f'(\infty)|<1$, then $\infty$ is an attracting fixpoint, so in Fatou set and THEN attracting basin at infinity is open and contained in Fatou set, whereas if $\infty$ is a repelling fixpoint then not?

Comment: I was thinking of *rational* functions, not of entire functions, so sorry for the confusion. (Perhaps you want to clarify that in your question). I am more familiar with the iteration of rational functions, therefore I do not have an answer to your question right now.

Comment: Theorem 2 in https://www.math.purdue.edu/~eremenko/dvi/banach.pdf might be what you are looking for: In the case of a transcendental entire function, $I(f)$ (what you call $A(\infty)$) always contains points of the Julia set, i.e. it is *not contained* in the Fatou set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is a non-linear polynomial, then $A(\infty)$ is open (to prove it, try to prove that there exists $R>0$ such that $A(\infty)=\bigcup_n f^{-n}\{ z \in \mathbb C : |z|>R \}$.

If $f$ is entire and not a polynomial, then as Martin R pointed out the escaping set $I(f)$ is not open (usually the term "basin" is reserved for open sets) and is not contained in the Fatou set.